# WooCommerce outdated templates overrides

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

After several year out, I'm trying to make a update to my wordpress and woocommerce. Unfortunatly, this is the message I got and I don't know where to go to fix it :

```
### Templates ###

Overrides: aurum/woocommerce/archive-product.php version 2.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.4.0
aurum/woocommerce/cart/cart-empty.php version 2.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 7.0.1
aurum/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php version 2.3.0 is out of date. The core version is 7.3.0
aurum/woocommerce/cart/cart.php version 2.3.8 is out of date. The core version is 7.9.0
aurum/woocommerce/cart/cross-sells.php version 1.6.4 is out of date. The core version is 4.4.0
aurum/woocommerce/cart/shipping-calculator.php version 2.0.8 is out of date. The core version is 7.0.1
aurum/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php version 2.1.2 is out of date. The core version is 3.6.0
aurum/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php version 2.3.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.5.0
aurum/woocommerce/checkout/form-login.php version 2.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.8.0
 [....]
aurum/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php version 2.3.2 is out of date. The core version is 4.3.0
aurum/woocommerce/single-product.php
aurum/woocommerce/content-product_cat.php version 2.4.0 is out of date. The core version is 4.7.0

Outdated Templates: ❌
```

Does someone as any idea of what I need to do to fix it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your theme "aurum" need to be updated: on the update process, at the same time inside your theme folder, the "woocommerce" subfolder (containing the outdated template overrides) will get updated (normally with the latest woocommerce template files).

Comment: Merci Loic. The thing is, when I look over wordpress administrative panel, I don't really find where I can update the theme : Nothing inside Appearance => Theme.

Comment: Maybe this templates have been customized via the theme some time ago, so in that case, you need to hire a developer to update those templates preserving the previous customizations...